# How to check in my contract the incomming amount?

Tags: smart-contract

I would like to check in my contract the incomming amount.

I tried these:

void mycontract(name from, name to, eosio::asset quantity, std::string memo){

```
    check( quantity.amount > 50, "must transfer only maximum 50 tokens/transaction" );
```

or

if(quantity.amount > 50) { }

But these not working.

Comment: I don't get error mesagess, but the if (...) always running...

Comment: yes used transfers.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're expecting this `check` to ensure that the amount is over 50.0 tokens, but the thing is that `asset.amount` is an integer, so let's say your token has 6 decimals, then you'd want this assertion to be:

```
check( quantity.amount > 50000000, "must transfer only maximum 50 tokens/transaction" );
```

more examples:

- `5.1234 EOS`'s `amount` will be 51234
- `20.0000000000 BNT`'s `amount` will be 200000000000

Comment: Thank You It is works fine.